# Select max value in a datatable with linq

Tags: vb.net

I have datatable which has three columns named "Step", "Disp" and "Shear". I wrote the following code:

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim maxStep As Object

    MaxStep = From n In VdTable Where n("Disp") > 0.05 And n("Shear") > 1600 Select n

End Sub
```

What I want to do is select max step value. But I don't want to cycle through all the elements in MaxStep. Because there is too much data in my datatable. Looking for the fastest way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gee, maybe the `Max` method?

Comment: @jim, definitely but I don't know how to use it. I am a civil engineer and my coding knowledge is limited.

Comment: Then do some reading on the subject and make an attempt. If you do that and it doesn't work, that would be the time to post a question here. Your coding knowledge may be limited but I'm sure that your internet knowledge is good enough for you to search for information on a subject.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've made a few assumptions here but you need to use `.Max()` method in your query.

```
Dim result = VdTable.AsEnumerable().Max(Function(t) t.Field(Of Integer)("Disp") > 0.05 AndAlso t.Field(Of Integer)("Shear") > 1600)
```

You could split this out into 2 `.Where()` clauses and then call `.Max()` if you prefer.